# In Wordprress, how can I make the width of an image larger than the -moz-column-width attribute I am using for text?

Tags: wordpress, css

When a Wordpress admin inserts a photo and some text, I have the text split into columns, using  -moz-column-width. The problem is that this also makes a photo contained by the same column width.

Ideally I'd like the image to fill the span of two columns or 100% of the content area instead of being the same width as one column of text.

The problem seems to be that Wordpress places images and text in the same paragraph tags with no way to target the image that I know of.

Any tips?

**Screenshot since my server is locked down:** http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4088146/Screenshots/h.png

```
<div class="post-text">
<h1 class="title" style="text-indent: 0px;">Viribus doloribus tempus, ratione quasi</h1>

<p><a href="http://make.truliablog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Leaderboards.png"><img width="1347" height="1237" alt="" src="http://make.truliablog.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/Leaderboards.png" title="Leaderboards" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-2470"></a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet dolorem proident utilitatis magnus agris. Abutebatur architecto propter ut materia. Quam quo aliquip, officii voluptatem. Qui pariatur officii eos.<br>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet cum tenetur animi. Et laboris aut aspexerat fugiat. Ipsa amet quoddam colebatur propter. Qui tempore et magna sibi. Id ipsum deinde, repellat minim. Mollit odit culpa qui aut. Adipisci vel delectus, pariatur propagabant. Consequatur sibi vero, voluptate consequatur. Ipsa colebatur et, pariatur repellendus. Dolor ullam consequatur id.<br>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your link gets me a 500 error.

Comment: fixed-my work server is apparently locked so I took a screenshot: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4088146/Screenshots/h.png and posted a code snipet

Comment: FYI, there's a dedicated WordPress Stack Exchange site. Really knowledgable people there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`column-span`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-span) property to make an element span more than one column.